# Symfony3.4 - Send a Server-Sent Event when something happens

Tags: events, websocket, symfony3.x

I'm developing a project with Symfony 3.4.

I would like to send a message to all the clients currently viewing a page when something happens. I evaluated both Server-Sent Events and Websockets, and I decided to go with the former, because the communication is unidirectional (only server to client).

For this purpose, I'm using this library: https://packagist.org/packages/tonyhhyip/sse

It seems to work, but I need to specifically send a message when something happens in the whole system. I tried with the Symfony event system (by creating a custom event), but events seem to be dispatched and captured only within the same session (i.e., the same logged user). In other words, if an action performed by a user triggers an event, it is not captured by other users and therefore a message is not sent to the browser via SSE.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve your issue?